# Tkinter - How can I destroy every widget in a frame without destroying the frame itself?

Tags: python, tkinter

So lets say I have `frm_one` which contains the widgets `lbl_one`, `btn_one`, `ent_one`, etc. How could I destroy each widget in `frm_one` without destroying the frame itself and without explicitly naming each widget?

If I do `frm_one.destroy()` it destroys the whole frame. I also want to be able to destroy all widgets regardless of what is in `frm_one` at any given time, since it could change. This means I can't just do `lbl_one.destroy()` `btn_one.destroy()` `ent_one.destroy()` and so on since there might be other widgets present at any moment.

Thank you, I am willing to share more details if possible.

Comment: Use `for widget in frm_one.winfo_children(): widget.destroy()`. The `.winfo_children()` lists all of the frame's children and the for loop destroys each one of them

Comment: This worked @TheLizzard thank you

Comment: A similar question: [How to delete all children elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995783/how-to-delete-all-children-elements)