# I can not find a way to clear the window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

```
import tkinter as tk

class main_window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        win_button = tk.Button(self, text="Searching and sorting algorithms",
                               command=self.window)
        win_button.grid(column=1,row=1)

        win_button2 = tk.Button(self, text="BIG 0",
                               command=self.window)
        win_button2.grid(column=3,row=1)

        win_button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Tree Traversal",
                               command=self.window)
        win_button3.grid(column=1, row=3)

        win_button4 = tk.Button(self, text="profix,infix and prefix",
                               command=self.window)
        win_button4.grid(column=3, row=3)

    def all_children (wid) :
        _list = wid.winfo_children()

        for item in _list :
            if item.winfo_children() :
                _list.extend(item.winfo_children())

        return _list

    def clear(self):
        list= root.grid_slaves()
        for k in list:
            k.destroy()


    def window(self):
        self.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    main_window(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make it create a screen which has the 4 selection. Then, the window will clear with which ever the user selected and pop with new information but I am having trouble with clearing. I have tried . destroy but it does work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Tkinter clearing a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781802/python-tkinter-clearing-a-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that you're calling `root.grid_slaves`, but the only window directly in root is managed by `pack` rather than `grid`.  Instead of using `root.grid_slaves()`, use `self.grid_slaves()` in `clear`.