# Creating a Python and Tkinter Login System

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written this code for login and registration...
But here I had first created different window popups for each action; Now I feel there should be only one window and all other popups to not appear...{I mean I wish to perform all this code in just one window but I'm unable to do it....}

***I want to replace windows so that the whole process takes place in only 1 WINDOW; please help!***

Thanks!

```
#import modules

from tkinter import *
import os

# Designing window for registration

def register():
    global register_screen
    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue", command = 
register_user).pack()


# Designing window for login 

def login():
    global login_screen
    login_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry

    Label(login_screen, text="Username * ").pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password * ").pack()
    password_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
    password_login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command = login_verify).pack()

# Implementing event on register button

def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(register_screen, text="Registration Success", fg="green", font=("calibri", 11)).pack()

# Implementing event on login button 

def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            login_sucess()

        else:
            password_not_recognised()

    else:
        user_not_found()

# Designing popup for login success

def login_sucess():
    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
    Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command=delete_login_success).pack()

# Designing popup for login invalid password

def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()

# Designing popup for user not found

def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()

# Deleting popups

def delete_login_success():
    login_success_screen.destroy()




def delete_password_not_recognised():
    password_not_recog_screen.destroy()


def delete_user_not_found_screen():
    user_not_found_screen.destroy()


# Designing Main(first) window

def main_account_screen():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Account Login")
    Label(text="Select Your Choice", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command = login).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()


main_account_screen()
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new window, [remove all the widgets in the current window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28623781/8321664) and draw your widgets on the same window after removing previous widgets.

Comment: Change windows to frames and switch to the frame you want.

Comment: @acw1668 I dunno how to switch frames...Please Help to modify the code